# I just had this thought. Can we find an identity that separates the product x.y in trig functions, i.e Cos(x.y)=f(x).g(y) or Sin(x.y) = f(x).g(y)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry, mathematical-physics

I just had this thought.   Can we find an identity that separates the product x.y in the trigonometric functions, i.e Cos(x.y)=f(x).g(y) or Sin(x.y) = f(x).g(y)... Where f(x) and g(y) are other trig functions,. Either as products or sums..?

Comment: The problem is that if $xy=a$ it's impossible to determine $x, y$

Comment: That would imply $\,\cos(x)=f(x)g(1)=f(1)g(x)\,$ then $\,\cos(xy)=\frac{\cos(x)\cos(y)}{f(1)g(1)}\,$ which cannot hold true.

Comment: If this worked, we wouldn't need double angle formulas, triple angle formulas, and the like; just the function $g$ and a table of values for $f.$ The fact that this isn't a standard feature of pages of trig identities (but the double angle formulas are) should be a hint.

Comment: No, there's no way to do this. One of the main reasons is that the product of two angles has no physical significance.

Answer (score 3):

The criteria for $\,A(x,y):=f(x)g(y)\,$ is that
$$A(x_1,y_1)A(x_2,y_2) =f(x_1)g(y_1)f(x_2)g(y_2) = A(x_1,y_2)A(x_2,y_1) \tag{1} $$ always holds.

In the case of the $\,\cos\,$ function, suppose there exist
functions $\,f,g\,$ such that
$$\cos(x\,y)=f(x)g(y). \tag{2} $$ Then the equation
$$ \cos(x_1y_1)\cos(x_2y_2) = \cos(x_1y_2)\cos(x_2y_1) \tag{3} $$ must be true. Specializing to the case
$\,x_2=y_2=0\,$ reduces this equation to
$\, \cos(x_1y_1) = 1 \,$ since
$\,\cos(0)=1.\,$ However, this is not true in general and thus,
there does not exist such functions $\,f,g.\,$

An similar result holds for the $\,\sin\,$ function.
Specializing to the case $\,x_2=\pi,y_2=1\,$ reduces equation
$(3)$ to $\,0=\sin(x_1)\sin(\pi y_1)\,$ since
$\,\sin(\pi)=0.\,$ However, this is not true in general and thus,
there does not exist such functions $\,f,g.\,$

Comment: While I agree with the reasoning provided for cosine, it seems insufficient for sine. In that case, we have $$\sin(x_1 y_1)\sin(x_2 y_2)=\sin(x_1 y_2)\sin(x_2 y_1).$$ Then the case $x_2=y_2=0$ merely yields $0=0$. (More broadly, any function $A(x,y)$ such that $A(x,0)=A(0,y)=0$ for all $x,y$ will always pass this test.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thanks for that comment! Will have to think about this.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we can go further; there are no (standard) trigonometric functions $f,g$ and no function $h$ with $\cos(xy) = h(f(x), g(y))$. Suppose there were; then we would have $1 = \cos(0)$ $= \cos((\frac14)\cdot 0)$ $= h(f(\frac14), g(0))$ $= h(f(\frac14), g(2\pi))$ $= \cos((\frac14)\cdot (2\pi))$ $= \cos(\frac\pi2) = 0$, where the middle equality is because $g(0) = g(2\pi)$ since $g$ has period $2\pi$.